# Selenium jxl reading incorrect data

Tags: java, selenium

I have written a script using selenium web driver, java and jxl where it is reading some data from sheet that is a numeric value. its taking some of the values incorrectly from sheet. For example if there are 500 entries in sheet then out of them 5 of the entries are incorrect. Suppose a entry is 66985 then it is taking 6985, other instance is ^6985. Every time i run the script it taking some of the id incorrectly. Different id's are taken wrong each time i run the code.

Here is the excerpts from my code

```
String id=sheet.getCell(1,i).getContents();
String data=datawithotTrim.trim();
                                                                                                       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='TB1']")).sendKeys(data);
```

Comment: Can you show your implementation for  the same ?

Comment: Kindly paste your code in question.

Comment: code is too long and i ma unable to post

Comment: Are U sure in System.out.println all data are correct?

Comment: Yes on the console window it is appearing correct but when i am sending it to text box there i am getting this problem                  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='TB1']")).sendKeys(data);           Here data is wrong. I have even taken screen shots for the same where it is showing $5869 instead of 45869, ^4578 instead of 64578 and 8965 instead of 78965